# How to get the url of the registered file for my iphone application?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I registered a file to my app for IOS. When I click on the file through the browser download, it opens up my application, but I am not able to actually receive a link to the actual file url. How can I do so? I just need to read in the file and my app stores its own copy. But the problem at hand right now is that, the app does not recognize when its being called upon when a registered file is clicked. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that after debugging, I can use the function in my AppDelegate.m file, namely the handleOpenURL function. It gets called, when the program gets ran with a url while the program is in the background. So from there, I used [[super webView] stringByEvaluatingJavascript] function, to communicate with the javascript.